# Cakephp 2.0: Same application, two tabs, two different values of a session variable?

Tags: tabs, cakephp-2.0, session-variables

Suppose that we have a session variable, x, with a value, x=2. In our application there's a link which opens, in another tab, another instance of our application with the only difference that our variable has a different value, say 3 (x=3). Is it possible to maintain the value 2 in the first tab continuing our work and the value 3 in the second and if yes how could I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Help me out here. why can't this be done via arrays ?

x['firstTab'] = 2;
x['secondTab'] = 3;

As far your question is concerned I am pretty much sure that you can not have two same variables in single session instance. If you create another session instance you will loose your previous session.